# How to remove previosly attached handler in jQuery properly

Tags: jquery

I know that I can remove a previously added event handler with the following:

```js
var func = function() {
    $('body').append('<div>' + this.a + '</div>');
  },
  a1 = $.proxy(func, {
    a: 1
  });
  
$('body').on('aa', a1);

$('body').off('aa', a1);


$('body').triggerHandler('aa');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My problem happens when I subscribe several different handlers for the same event and somehow all of the previously added handlers are removed instead of the specified:

```js
var func = function() {
    $('body').append('<div>' + this.a + '</div>');
  },
  a1 = $.proxy(func, {
    a: 1
  }),
  a2 = $.proxy(func, {
    a: 2
  }),
  a3 = $.proxy(func, {
    a: 3
  });
  
$('body').off('aa', a1).on('aa', a1);
$('body').off('aa', a2).on('aa', a2);
$('body').off('aa', a3).on('aa', a3);

$('body').off('aa', a1).on('aa', a1);
$('body').off('aa', a2).on('aa', a2);
$('body').off('aa', a3).on('aa', a3);

$('body').triggerHandler('aa');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I think this example should print out 1 2 3, but it prints 3 only as every previous handler removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above approach doesn't work because they're all proxied to the same function:

> Handlers proxied by jQuery.proxy() or a similar mechanism will all have the same unique id (the proxy function), so passing proxied handlers to .off may remove more handlers than intended. In those situations it is better to attach and remove event handlers using namespaces. http://api.jquery.com/off/

An example of the namespace approach:

```js
var func = function() {
    $('body').append('<div>' + this.a + '</div>');
  },
  a1 = $.proxy(func, {
    a: 1
  }),
  a2 = $.proxy(func, {
    a: 2
  }),
  a3 = $.proxy(func, {
    a: 3
  });

$('body').on('aa.one', a1);
$('body').on('aa.two', a2);
$('body').on('aa.three', a3);

$('body').triggerHandler('aa'); // triggers all three

$('body').off('aa.two').off('aa.three'); // cancel two handlers

$('body').triggerHandler('aa'); // triggers only the remaining aa.one
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well I missid it in the jQuery documentation: "Handlers proxied by jQuery.proxy() or a similar mechanism will all have the same unique id (the proxy function), so passing proxied handlers to .off may remove more handlers than intended. In those situations it is better to attach and remove event handlers using namespaces."

Comment: Entertainingly enough, I was just in the process of discovering the same thing when you posted that comment :)  I always use namespaced events if I'm going to be turning them off later, it's just easier to see in the code.

Comment: I have a very big hierarchy of objects and the several same type of object can attach themself to the same parent. I thought if I proxy their function I can add and remove them just fine as the handlers are not equal. Now I need to generate unique identifiers for every objects to be able to namespace them properly.

Comment: In that case it may be simpler to modify the function itself -- set a data attribute on the element to say whether or not the handler should fire, an instead of turning off the event handler have the function check for the presence/absence of the attribute before doing anything.  Means you'll have some no-op events firing, but it may be worth it if it reduces your code complexity...

Comment: Yeah, but the objects can move from their parent object to a new parent object and when it happen I want to remove the event handler from the old parent. :)

Also  could could you modify your answer with the jQuery doc quote I added in the comment section? Then I will accept your solution.